# Regla htaccess en mi web

Tags: web

tengo esta regla en mi htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) / [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Yo quiero que si la url no comienza con ´https://www.´, la redireccione y comience con ella.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes anteponer la regla

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

A tu regla `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` de manera que quedase

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Esto generaría tres tipos de redirección

```
request: http://www.midominio.com
  redirect-> https://www.midominio.com (regla2)

request: http://midominio.com
  redirect-> https://www.midominio.com (regla1)

request: https://midominio.com
  redirect-> https://www.midominio.com (regla1)
```

El cuarto caso es

```
request: https://www.midominio.com
```

Y ese no está sujeto a redirección.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho!! estaba haciendo eso mismo pero ponia 1 solo tipo de redireccion no mas de 1. Gracias. sabia que estaba cerca!!

Answer (score 1):

Después del `RewriteEngine On` añade la siguiente línea:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

El resto de tu `htaccess` podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) / [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```